# Binding Text Styles (Font Attributes) in the Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin Forms and I am trying to bind the styling dynamically from the database.
For example, I am binding a content which has couple of paragraphs and the styles for each paragraphs are different. Some are bold, some are bold and italics etc. So I want to know how I can bind the styles to the label like below.

In the variable the Value "Bold" is coming from Database.

It will be a great help if you can guide me in this so that I can move on with the project.

Thanks in Advance

<Label Text="Test" **FontAttribute="{Binding fontAttribute}**/>

Comment: I don't believe `FontAttributes` is bindable

Comment: @Jason https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/4f3acdfb0bc98e3ba8e2f3eae86e88602350ee84/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Label.cs#L42

Comment: Can you show us your View and your ViewModel for this property?

Comment: huh - generally the docs make it clear when a property in bindable.  Good to know.

Comment: Your code says `FontAttribute`. Do you mean `FontAttributes` (plural)?

Comment: As my friend Chat said, since the FontAttribute property is an enumeration (FontAttributes), it cannot be directly bound to a property from the code-behind, but can do via a value converter

Comment: You can declare the type of the **fontAttribute** variable in the viewmodel as the **FontAttributes** not a string.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, yes, its FontAttributes

Comment: It is up to you to write code to convert the strings from database to a [FontAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.fontattributes?view=xamarin-forms) value. Try putting that in a property `public FontAttributes TheFontAttributes { get; set; }`, and binding to that. However, I'm not sure if Xamarin.Forms ever made enums like `FontAttributes` work in a Binding. You might need to write a [Value Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters).